# Debugging do-while loop appear more than one statements

Tags: java

I write a code for o-while loop where I take an input from user  and check if it is equal to 'c' or 'C' the exit from the loop. If input other than c or C entered the internal statement of do block is appearing 3 times and if i just enter press without pressing any character then do block's inner statement appears 2 times why?? Can anyone explain

```
int ch = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Press C or c to continue.");
            ch = System.in.read();
        }
        while(ch !='C' && ch !='c');
```

Comment: Because pressing enter without a character still reads a character, namely the newline symbol (`\n`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Judging from the output you described, you are probably on a Windows machine, right?)

`read` returns the next character in the input stream. When you enter C or c, and then press enter, you have actually entered three characters:

- `c`
- `\r`
- `\n`

The last two characters together is the Windows way of representing a new line. Since there are three characters to read, `read` gets called three times before you are prompted to enter anything again, so `println` gets called three times as well.

If you just press enter, then you have only entered two characters:

- `\r`
- `\n`

so two lines are printed.

To fix this, you can use a [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). `Scanner` has a nice method called [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), which returns everything the user enters until it reaches a new line character.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = "";
do {
    System.out.println("Press C or c to continue.");
    line = sc.nextLine();
}
while(!ch.equals("C") && !ch.equals("c"));
```